# post request using bootstrap-confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using BS-3 and bs-confirmation https://github.com/tavicu/bs-confirmation.

I have a button in my html which I click on, it display yes or no and then I can click on yes or no button

```
<a data-href="/api/yes-no/" class="btn" data-toggle="confirmation">Confirmation</a>
```

and javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('body').confirmation({
      selector: '[data-toggle="confirmation"]',
      btnOkLabel: 'Yes',
      btnCancelLabel: 'No',
      btnOkClass: "btn btn-sm btn-success",
      btnCancelClass: "btn btn-sm btn-danger"
    });
    $('.confirmation-callback').confirmation({
      onConfirm: function() { console.log('YES') },
      onCancel: function() { console.log('NO') }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I want to send yes or no(whichever user click on) to my API (`/api/yes-no/`) using POST method.

but when I click on yes/no it open the api page(I mean GET request) how can I make it POST with form field ({'type': 'YES' or 'No' or anyother boolean})

Answer (score 0):

`onConfirm` function is attached to the element you are initially clicking on, so you can use it to get `data-href` and then use standard jQuery method to invoke `POST` request.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('body').confirmation({
        selector: '[data-toggle="confirmation"]',
        btnOkLabel: 'Yes',
        btnCancelLabel: 'No',
        btnOkClass: "btn btn-sm btn-success",
        btnCancelClass: "btn btn-sm btn-danger",
        onConfirm: function () {
            $.post(
                $(this).attr('data-href'),
                {}, // you data for POST body
                function (data) {
                    // act on the response
                }
            );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```